# Remaining work for bugs not included in work details in TFS 2017.2

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

I have bugs that have values in the **remaining work** field that I want to show up when the column is visible and also count towards the assigned work for a user in the **Work Details** section in TFS when looking at a sprint.

I have the **Working with Bugs** setting set to *Bugs are managed with requirements* as I want the bugs to appear in the backlog along with product backlog items and don't want to have to create a task for each bug to manage their remaining time.

I can get this working if I change the **Working with bugs** setting to *Bugs are managed with tasks* but then all bugs are grouped together and show up as *Unparented* and I can't order them with Product Backlog Items. So that doesn't really work for what i'm trying to achieve.

I really want to have a mix of bugs and product backlog items in a sprint assigned to multiple users and easily see how many hours each user has assigned to them so the week can be planed out.

Is there a setting that can be put against the bug work item type to make sure the remaining work will show up in the work details section and the burndown chart?

A bit about our setup:

- We are using TFS 2017 Update 2 on premise
- Using Scrum process template
- Working with bugs setting is set to "Bugs are managed with requirements"

Comment: Did you try the methods below, does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

In TFS sprint backlog, it doesn't list the remaining work value set inside each bug if you set “Bugs are managed with requirements”. It shows the sum of all Remaining Work of all tasks under this Bug in Sprint backlog. About this setting, it is introduced in this [document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields).

But there're some other methods that you could try:

1. You could create work item queries to get the remaining work values for each bug in a sprint. Add the remaining work field column.
   [image]
2. You could use **sprint board**, add the remaining work field to the card. 
   [image]